# Differential equations online courses

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

Can anybody, please, give a links or some advices to good differential equations online courses? I had one in university and recently realised I know nothing about them, and still can't solve them.
May be I had badly tried Coursera, bit didn't succeeded with searching there.

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Most ODEs don't have a straightforward solution, so the "can't solve" part shouldn't be upsetting or surprising.:)  I would recommend first studying this source: https://books.google.com/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=arnold+ordinary+differential+equations&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKuteG7eLPAhWDWj4KHVPMBxsQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=Counterexample&f=false

Comment: @user8960 Oh! Arnold! Heard a lot about his works and read some, but in other areas of maths. The plus is I can read his book in russian :) Thanx!)

Comment: @Moo Not very concrete, but I can find smth there, surely. However, that would be more interesting, if you took any of that courses and can give a simple feedback =)

Comment: @Moo That are good questions! I think I need some intro, yes. But not very.. how to say.. stupid. No, I don't need some courses for solving DE in matlab or smth like this. My skill.. I can solve a simple linear DE:) I need smth like a university course for its level.